# Android Retrofit Error

Tags: android, retrofit

I have made an application that will make a request with some parameters to Google API that will return JSON as a response..
The problem is that this request will be made every 2 seconds.
So now here my logcat is showing some error and calling failure() everytime

here is my logcat:

```
09-14 18:03:55.338   8080-10980/com.example.akshay.retrofitgsonjsonarray D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR
09-14 18:03:55.348   8080-10980/com.example.akshay.retrofitgsonjsonarray D/Retrofit﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: api.getData: URL query string "path={latlong}&interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyDAsAs9k2dQ6aDMUlgLcE-dTxAOxMtADTU" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:107)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parsePath(RestMethodInfo.java:210)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseMethodAnnotations(RestMethodInfo.java:149)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:117)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:294)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-14 18:03:55.348   8080-10980/com.example.akshay.retrofitgsonjsonarray D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

Every time the value of logcat will be changed so I am confused what is going wrong.

The problem is here I guess but I am not able to sort it out

```
package com.example.akshay.retrofitgsonjsonarray;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 9/8/2015.
 */
public interface api {
    @GET("/snapToRoads?path={latlong}&interpolate=true&key=KEY")
    public void getData(@Query("latlong") String latlng, Callback<SnappedPointsContainer> response);
}
```

any help ..
thanks

Comment: Can you try this ? 
 @GET("/snapToRoads?interpolate=true&key="googlekey")
    public void getData(@Query("path") String latlng, Callback<SnappedPointsContainer> response);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error says,
api.getData: URL query string "path={latlong}&interpolate=true&key=GOogle api key" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query

you already had latlong as query parameter with latlong so you can remove path from hardcoded url query string and rename the query field as path.

```
@GET("/snapToRoads?interpolate=true&key="googlekey") 
public void getData(@Query("path") String latlng, Callback<SnappedPointsContainer> response);
```

On a side note : You should not sharing your google api key publicly.

Comment: That Works.. Thank you my friend :)

Comment: Are you on facebook ?

Comment: you can get details from my website in stackoverflow profile :)

Answer (score 1):

It is good to do like above answer for small data fetch like you are fetching data from one and two directories of your Api but for dynamic doing all thing .
you need to put your base url in string.xml
Like: example.com

And Your Interface

```
public interface api {
@GET("/snapToRoads")
public void getData(@Query("path") String latlng, @Query("interpolate") boolean interpolate , @Query("key") String key Callback<SnappedPointsContainer> response);}
```

SnappedPointsContainer Pojo in which data come

Don't need to use {anything} Path parameter in this , here you are sending  three query only
good luck ...